# How can I pass a value to a javascript function on the parent page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, iframe, parent

How could I pass a value to a function on a parent page?

Would it be something similar to this?

```
parent.functionname("VALUE")
```

Comment: this is executing in an iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

As long as both pages are in the same domain, you can access the global scope (`window` object) of the parent frame using the frame's `parent` object.

You can use any global data (functions or variables) by writing `parent.whatever`.